# How can i submit two different forms at the same time?

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I have made a script that allowes a user to fill in his username. He can also select an amount of money to donate on paypal. Every money amount that you donate, i want the script to give the user a specific amount of tokens on his account for the payment. I will update the tokens amount with a simple update query. But from what i've heard is that it's not possible to donate money and at the same time update the tokens. Because for the paypal donation it uses another form action:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" Find account "/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html> 

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Tokens">Tokens</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="10">10 $0.01 USD</option>
    <option value="50">50 $0.01 USD</option>
    <option value="100">100 $0.01 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="User Name">User Name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="encrypted value">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know of a way to submit two forms, but as for the root of your problem I do have a solution. Paypal has callback routes it can hit depending on payment status, so for example you could use the callback route for after they finish a donation and use that to trigger a php script to update the tokens.